# microsoft navision 2009, break line

Tags: navision

I want to have a return line:

```
showmoreDetailsAddress :=LocLocationtClientMethod.City + ',' + ' ' + LocLocationtClientMethod."Post Code" + ',' + ' ' +
LocLocationtClientMethod.Address;
```

Because now every propertie is on the same line. But each property has to be on a seperate line, like this:

```
a
b
c
```

I have try it like this:

```
showmoreDetailsAddress :=LocLocationtClientMethod.City + ',' + '\' + LocLocationtClientMethod."Post Code" + ',' + ' ' +
LocLocationtClientMethod.Address;
```

but then still the result is:

```
AMSTERDAM,\1043AP, sdljkglsdjkfg
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on where you are going to use the result. For Nav new line is `\` slash. For everything else new line is `chr(13)+chr(10)`

For form fields [Multiline property must also be set to Yes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355043.aspx).

Comment: @SavantTheIncredible if you want to output multiple lines to field on form you should mention this in question. See the edit.